# Land into Ubuntu 16.04 directly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

When I start my laptop Dell 5459, I get a boot screen of Dell and after that Windows 10 starts loading. If I have to load Ubuntu, then I have to press F12 and then choose hard-drive from the menu (which has USB as the other option). I want directly to land-up in Ubuntu. It will be better if I get an option like I have to choose Boot options, but Ubuntu has to be default booting OS.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your boot order in the BIOS settings. Unfortunately I can't tell you exact steps because each machine kind of has its own bios interface. If you provide a picture of it maybe I can help better.

Go into your settings and search for something like "**boot order**" or "**boot options**", probably under "advanced options". You should see the windows partition (or maybe hard disk) listed above Ubuntu's. Move Ubuntu to be the first option, save and exit and it should be fine.

Sometimes it doesn't say which partition has what OS so you have to find a way to know. Try identifying by the sizes of your partitions.

*comment if anything seems unclear...*

Answer (score 0):

Try this within Windows 10. It allows you to change boot preference, wait time, default OS etc. Just a few clicks is only that is required.

http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/